# Allow null value but not allow empty String in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have a case when i try to validate a property of an php PHP object, this property can be null but not empty string.
Is it possible to do it with a single annotation like:

```
class JustAnObject
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlankNullable
     */
     private $Property;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible in symfony 4.3 you can do:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class JustAnObject
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(allowNull = true)
     */
    private $property;
}
```